# Navigation Bar don't charge correctly the first time

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I am developing an app that contains a login and when logging in for the first time the views that go after logging do not load well the navigation bar, when opening the app for the second time and already with the credentials previously entered, this time if they load well the navigation bar.
Does anyone know why this happens?
my viewWillAppear is like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 38, height: 38))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "img_header")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView

        //let image_home = UIImage(named: "ic_home")
        //let homeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image_home, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelMetod2))
        // navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton

        let color_primary: UIColor = val_colores.hexStringToUIColor(val_colores.colorPrimary)
        let color_background_primary: UIColor = val_colores.hexStringToUIColor(val_colores.ColorGrisClaro2)

        //icono more
        let imagen_more = UIImage (named: "ic_more_menu")!
        let buttonMore: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: imagen_more, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done,target: self, action: #selector(self.moreMetod))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonMore

        //background color
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = color_primary
        //back button color
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = color_background_primary
        //Since iOS 7.0 UITextAttributeTextColor was replaced by NSForegroundColorAttributeName
        //title color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color_background_primary]
        //color in carrier, hour, battery
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.black

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color_background_primary]
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = color_background_primary
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I think, your question cannot be answered as it is - we need code! Please edit your question and add the relevant code, and many here will try top help you.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, I already made the change

Comment: when your app opens is this the first screen you show or not?

Comment: no, the first view is a welcome page, is only a view with logo and 2 buttons